# How to optimise my solution to HackerRank's Largest Rectangle problem?

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to solve the Largest Rectangle problem on HackerRank (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/largest-rectangle/problem) in python.

> There are a number of buildings in a certain two-dimensional
> landscape. Each building has a height, given by `h[i]`. If you join
> `k` adjacent buildings, they will form a solid rectangle of area `k * min(h[i], h[i + 1], ..., h[i + k - 1])`.
>
> Example
>
> `h = [3, 2, 3]`
>
> A rectangle of height `h = 2` and length `k = 3` can be constructed within the
> boundaries. The area formed is `h * k = 2 * 3 = 6`.

I got a suboptimal solution with the following code:

```
def area(h, i_start, k):
    return k*min(h[i_start:i_start+k])

def largestRectangle(h):
    largestArea = 0
    for i_start in range(len(h)):
        for k in range(1,len(h)-i_start+1):
            thisArea = area(h, i_start, k)
            if thisArea > largestArea:
                largestArea = thisArea
    return largestArea
```

While this works on many of the smaller test cases, it times out on the larger ones; I believe it's O(n^2) where n is the length of h.

I'd like to get a faster version, but I don't see how to avoid checking all widths k. Indeed, if after a certain point, the h's decline only very slightly, we'd want to make the rectangle as wide as possible, but if the decline is faster, then we should not widen the rectangle.
Does anyone have a possible hint?

Comment: You can try divide and conquer for an O(n) solution: The largest rectangle it either the area under the lowest point or (recursion) the largest rectangle to either side of it.

Comment: This worked, thanks so much! If you post it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.